# How to deploy Liferay portlets using WAS Administration Console

Tags: websphere, liferay, liferay-6, websphere-7

After deploying Liferay war on [WAS 7.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp),

> How to deploy any of the liferay plugins war?

I can deploy plugins war in a same way as I deployed Liferay portal war and it also shows that apllication is started and running but I can't see the portlet in Liferay's Add more option or any where.

Any Help is Appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: see the log file, if deploy was success, then see the liferay-portlet.xml. May be the portlet is hidden.

Comment: No It's not hidden. I guess need more configuration with WAS and deployed Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Copy the portlet WAR file into Liferay's autodeploy directory. Liferay will process the plugin configuration files and generate a new WAR into a destination directory.
2. Deploy this newly generated WAR using Websphere admin console.

The path where Liferay leaves the preprocessed WAR is configurable via the auto.deploy.* properties in the portal.properties file. Take a look there to see where to look for the file.